# Does the airburst effect of a meteor depend on the chemical composition of the atmosphere?

Tags: reentry, meteors

Does the magnitude and character of an airbursting meteor depend substantially on whether it hits an atmosphere with much O2, N2 or CO2? Does the oxygen in Earth's atmosphere affect meteors?

Assume that density and everything's the same. Does the chemistry of the atmosphere matter much for how the impactor behaves on entry? Are for example meteors different at Venus and Mars than on Earth?

Comment: See [Physics-Based Modeling of Meteor Entry and Breakup](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150018060.pdf) (PDF), and you might want to see [videos](http://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/content/search?SearchText=Planetary+Defense+Conference&SearchButton=Go) of the [4th IAA Planetary Defense Conference](http://www.pdc2015.org/) where this was discussed in detail (program [here](http://iaaweb.org/iaa/Scientific%20Activity/draftprogrampdc2015.pdf) that should help you find the presentations). Basically, no. It's an aerothermodynamic process, not a chemical one.

Comment: You may be interested in [Can Venus' Surface Get Hit Hard?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/34987/29) on [worldbuilding.se], which approaches a similar question from a different angle. Bottom line there: the meteor and the atmosphere don't have much time to interact with each other.